Given that node modules can't be used, suggest an approach integrating Roomle with Salesforce
The rooomle documentation says there are two ways to incorporate rubens configurator.
First approach is to install the roomle package from npm, this is not possible in my use case. The second approach says to include a script tag in the html, but its not entirely clear how to obtain the link to the javascript file (this one <script src="./roomle-configurator-api.es.min.js" type="module"></script>). The file roomle-configurator-api.es.min.js is not available under the npm package either, I have checked under the installed npm package too.
Can you provide the http link to the referred js file?
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Since version 5 of the Roomle embedding lib, it should be roomle-embedding-lib.es.min.js
Here is a minimal example of how to use it: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/roomle-vanilla-js-embedding-js-file-5-2-2-r3pvhc?file=%2Findex.js
We'll update the documentation accordingly.
